# Google wallet error: The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http"

Tags: javascript, in-app-purchase, android-pay

I'm trying to get up and running with google wallet and am following the ["get started" tutorial](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial). When I put in the call for the javascript library

```
<script src="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/lib/buy.js"></script>
```

I get the following error in my console:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://sandbox.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:12098".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
 inject.js:211
(anonymous function) inject.js:211
```

I have attempted to use

```
<script src="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/lib/buy.js"></script>
```

but I get the same error. I have even put my app online at an https address and still get the error. Is there a trick I'm missing to get this to load?

Comment: Use `http` instead of `https`

Comment: Apologies - I meant to say that I'd actually tried that. So I put the src as http://sandbox...etc. but still no joy.

Comment: Actually that does solve the problem. I opened my app in incognito (with http instead of https) and it didn't produce the error. It seems it was some kind of cache problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you can solve this by using http instead of https.

Also make sure to empty your cache. In chrome press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd>

Comment: I'd give another +1 for the cool use of <kbd> and Unicode symbols (even if this is frequently used around here, I hadn't seen it)