# Using Google Wallet's Sample file gives error

Tags: php, android-pay

I've implemented the sample code found at https://code.google.com/p/iap-php/ on my test site http://whatisthesite.com. As you might be able to see there is a vague error message once the "Purchase" button is clicked:

```
There is an error in the setup for your purchase. Please contact the merchant with this error message: Expected 3 components in jwt: $jwtToken
```

The console gives:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://whatisthesite.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://sandbox.google.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.
 markdown-here.js:33
findFocusedElem markdown-here.js:33
intervalCheck
```

The demo site http://iap-php.appspot.com/ is not https: nor is there anywhere in the code to define the protocol. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

UPDATE:

It has something to do with the sample's use of "Here Doc" syntax to use inline PHP variables in JS functions. Changed this syntax:

```
echo <<< INDEX <button id='runDemoButton' value='buy' class='buy-button' onclick='DemoButton("$jwtToken");'><b>Purchase</b></button> INDEX;
```

to this:

```
<button id='runDemoButton' value='buy' class='buy-button' onclick='DemoButton("<?php echo $jwtToken;?>");'><b>Purchase</b></button>
```

But now gives an even more vague error.

Comment: Are you using _sandbox_ account (secret/id)?

Comment: That was the issue!The sandbox id's vs the production ids. Thank you for getting me out of my own head @EdSF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialog errors such as "There is an error in the setup for your purchase" have a corresponding error code returned to the client-side failure handler:

https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/jsreference#failurehandler

In your case the error code is MERCHANT_ERROR which indicates a badly formatted JWT. This may be due to using the incorrect SELLER KEY or SECRET to sign the JWT.

Comment: You're referring to the failure handler that is console logging? Yeah, also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157243/google-wallet-error-the-frame-requesting-access-has-a-protocol-of-https-the?rq=1 solved another issue. Thank you @Mihai